# JDK 8 for Mac OSX 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, java-8

I have an old Mac laptop that has OSX 10.11 El Capitan on it.  It can't load a later version of Mac OS.  I noticed on the Azul site that their JDK 8 only works on 10.13 or later.  I, therefore, wonder what the latest version of JDK 8 that I can install on OSX 10.11.  The Oracle site still has older JDK 8's for download.  I searched on the net but couldn't find an answer.  Sure appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Blake McBride

Comment: Have you tried installing it anyway and see if it runs?

Comment: No.  There are too many versions.

Comment: Grab the latest version of Java 8 for Intel Mac from Azul or AdoptOpenJDK, see if it works. The listed system requirements may refer to what they use for testing rather than actual requirement.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://download.bell-sw.com/java/16.0.2+7/bellsoft-jdk16.0.2+7-macos-amd64.dmg) too?

Comment: By the way, you can install BSD or Linux instead of macOS on some older Macs.

Comment: I tried installing Linux in the past and it worked well.

Comment: (I had some time machine backups I needed so I put OSX back on it.)

Comment: Why do you need java 8 and not a later version?

Comment: I use java mainly for the products described at https://kissweb.org/ and https://www.arahant.com/  Haven't had enough of a need to go forward.  I'll likely move to Java 17 and skip the rest.  Until then, Java 8 works well, and being able to demo on the Mac is convenient.  (The Macs have the best batter life!)

Answer (score 1):

Download the JDK for Mac from https://adoptopenjdk.net/releases.html?variant=openjdk8&jvmVariant=hotspot

It says it supports MacOS 10.10 and later.